# Continuity in set functions

Tags: measure-theory, limits, continuity

Let a function be defined as $f:(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F}_1)\rightarrow (\Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_2)$, where $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are $\sigma$-fields in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively.

If $f$ is continuous then for all $F^1_n \uparrow F^1$, $F^1_n \;\in \mathcal{F}_1$, 
$$f(F^1_n) \rightarrow f(F^1)$$

*i.e.* $$\lim_n \sup f(F^1_n) = \lim_n \inf f(F^1_n) = \lim_n f(F^1_n).$$

What I want to know is, whether there is any other standard definition of continuity for these functions *i.e.* the other definition holds iff this definition holds.

For *e.g.* in metric spaces the following definitions are equivalent,

1. $x_n \rightarrow x$ $\Leftrightarrow f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$
2. $f^{-1}(A)$ for every open set $A$ is open

My question is motivated from the definition of continuity in section 1.5.1 in [Robert Ash](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=GkqQoRpCO2QC).

Comment: These need not be topologies on $\mathcal{F}_i$, $i=1,2$ even if you defined all convergent sequences. These particularly may not be  topologies if $\mathcal{F_i}$ is atomless in the sense of each $F\in \mathcal{F}_i$ contains a measurable non-empty strict-subset.

Comment: @RabeeTourky strictly speaking, $f$ is a correspondence. What is the definition for continuity for $f$, and is there any other equivalent definition. It may be completely different than the above 2 given for metric spaces.

Comment: I think you want $\Rightarrow$, not $\Leftrightarrow$ in definition "1".